# How to exclude Customers who sold product A but not Product B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm feeling pretty dumb because I cannot wrap my head around how to write this.

We want to return customers who have purchased Product A but not Product B. B typically goes along with A so its a sales opportunity.

Data that I'm pulling from is order data down at the line item level. Right now I'm pulling just Customer Name and Product, then grouping so I have a list of products by customer, results look like this:

| PrimaryCustomer | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | Product A |
| Customer 1 | Product B |
| Customer 1 | Product C |
| Customer 2 | Product A |
| Customer 2 | Product C |

I need to return only Customer 2, because they purchased Product A but not Product B. Customer 1 did, so I need to remove them.

Comment: See this article titled "Find Customers Who Bought "A" and "B" But Not "C"" - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/find-customers-who-bought-a-and-b-but-not-c-sql-spackle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select PrimaryCustomer
from t
where product in ('A', 'B')
group by PrimaryCustomer
having max(product) = 'A';
```

This uses the ordering of the products.  That is cheating perhaps.  So, you might find this more general:

```
having min(product) = max(product) and min(product) = 'A'
```

Assuming you have one row per customer/product, you can also use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.product = 'A' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.PrimaryCustomer = t.PrimaryCustomer and
                        t2.product = 'B'
                 );
```

This has the advantage that it is easy to return other columns from the table.

Comment: I was getting close. I had started to work on it with NOT EXISTS but I wasn't using the joins inside correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Among them:

```
select primarycustomer from mytable where product = 'Product A'
except
select primarycustomer from mytable where product = 'Product B'
```